# Detecting Completion of an Array of Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have created an array of threads and started all of them. How to know whether all threads have completed work. I don't want to use thread.wait or thread.join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *can* test [`Thread.IsAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive.aspx) - but that will be out of date as soon as you've tested it, of course. You could keep a list of "currently alive" threads, and remove them one at a time when they stop, sleeping between test runs. For more detailed information you can use [`Thread.ThreadState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.threadstate.aspx).

What's the bigger picture here? What are you trying to achieve, and why don't you want to call `Thread.Join` (potentially with a timeout)?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .NET 4 you could use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and the [ContinueWhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473.aspx) method.

You'd have to modify your threads to be represented as [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)'s. Tasks are easier to work with then threads. Usually you do not have to worry about lower-level things as you are forced to do now like scheduling or waiting for things to complete.

Answer (score 0):

What about MyThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped ?

Comment: It should be `(MyThread.ThreadState & System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped` since `ThreadState` has the FlagsAttrbiute and thus can "contain" more values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ThreadPool class instead of an array, and use the 'GetAvailableThreads' method to check if all threads are available. See:

[`ThreadPool` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have the threads call back to the class that you started them in to signal that they are done

Answer (score 0):

if you want to intercept the work asynchronously you can use BackgroundWorkers all of which have a RunWorkerCompleted event and a Error and Cancelled properties in the event args

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx